# How can I tell git which vim to use?

Tags: git, vim, version-control, vim-plugin, git-commit

When I edit a commit message with vim (by entering `git commit`), vim opens, but first with a prompt that the [YouCompleteMe plugin](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) is unavailable:

```
$ git commit
YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim 7.3.584+
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When I check the version using `:version` after pressing `ENTER`, I see that vim 7.3 is running. However, if I start vim directly from the command line (not using `git commit`), I see that I'mrunning vim 7.3.754. How can I tell git to use the newer version of vim?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
git config --global core.editor /my/version/of/vim
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! FWIW, I only had to use "vim", not the full path, because I had previously created a symlink from there to /usr/local/bin/mvim as suggested in the installation instructions for YouCompleteMe: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe

Answer (score 2):

This solved my issue.

```
git config --global core.editor `which vim`
```